# Can I have a question removed from my account

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts

I asked this question, [Should I tell my employer that I need to appear in court](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57480/should-i-tell-my-employer-that-i-need-to-appear-in-court). It was useful for me and probably will be for others, but I probably shouldn't have that attached to the account I use for work. Is there a way I can be disassociated with it without deleting it?

Not a duplicate of [How should we handle work sensitive questions?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-should-we-handle-work-sensitive-questions) because my focus is on past questions after the mistake has been made.

Comment: Did you already flag the question for moderator attention?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should we handle work sensitive questions?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-should-we-handle-work-sensitive-questions)

Comment: @gnat I don't see how that's a dupe.  This asks how to disassociate; that asks how careful one should be.

Comment: @MonicaCellio check [the answer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/143/168) over there: "You can ask Stack Exchange to disassociate the question from your account..."

Comment: But we evaluate duplicates based on the *question*, not on the *answers*.

Comment: @MonicaCellio that's not how I read [MSE guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707): _"if the other question helps them, they're happy because they got an answer... this is subtly different from saying "If that other question isn't asking the exact same thing as yours..." That's because **the proof is in the answers**...  we now indicate "This question already has an answer here"... The fundamental goal of dupes is to help people find the right answer by getting all of the answers in one place... much better experience for the asker and the Googler **who just want to find an answer**."_

Comment: In this case, both the question __AND__ answers on the "possible duplicate" don't apply here so the distinction doesn't really matter.

Comment: Now you have to have this question disassociated too!  I would create another meta question to delete you from this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators cannot disassociate posts, but employees can.  The most efficient way to make this happen, therefore, is to use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.  Include the URL of the post you want to disassociate and ask them to do it.  The post, and any rep changes that came from it, will be disconnected from your account.

If you use a flag to request this, mods will just turn around and forward it to the community managers once we see it.  So you might as well cut out the middleman.