# I cant delete my account or post?

Tags: discussion

How to do I delete my account and post? Under edit my profile there's nothing there I can't find how to delete it anywhere.

Comment: [Help Center -> How do I delete my account?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) (FWIW you can also edit your real name out from your profile)

Answer (score 6):

You can't delete the question because it has upvoted answers on it.  These are still valuable to the greater community, and so it remains as part of the knowledge base of the site.

You can request a Stack Exchange employee delete your account from the [Contact Us](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the main page.   You'll see a list of reasons for contacting, and deleting your account is one of the options.  Once deleted, your questions will remain but they will not be associated with any user.

You can *also* request that the question be [disassociated from your account](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/can-i-have-a-question-removed-from-my-account?rq=1).  Just use the Contact Us link as for requesting account deletion but ask for disassociation of the question.